# How to automatically hide error messages in GNOME Shell's notifications?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, ruby, libnotify

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and gnome-shell 3. I`m using Guard to notify test pass or failure.

How to automatically hide error messages from libnotify in gnome shell?

When I have green test notification hide automatically after few seconds but When my test have errors I have to click on error messages to hide because they are overlay all other notifications.

How to setup autohide for errors??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know, you can't. The reason the errors don't disappear is because their urgency is probably set to CRITICAL, and gnome-shell's behavior is to always expand those, and only close on click. You may be able to change the urgency of the error notifications in you app. Check it's documentation.